# How to change axis values in Matlab (imhist command)

Tags: image, matlab, histogram

```
%boat_image&histogram
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(I01);
subplot(1,2,2)
imhist(I01);
saveas( gcf, 'boat_image&histogram', 'jpg' );
```

[image]
I want to cover all y values. How can I change the axis values in terms of the covering maximum value?

after adding following commands, I recieved a different histogram below.

```
%boat_image&histogram
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(I02);
subplot(1,2,2)
[cts,x] = imhist(I02);
stem(cts,x);
ylim([0,max(x)]);
saveas( gcf, 'boat_image&histogram_', 'jpg' );
```

[image]

after switch:

```
%boat_image&histogram
 subplot(1,2,1)
    imshow(I02);
    subplot(1,2,2)
    [x,cts] = imhist(I02);
    stem(x,cts);
    ylim([0,max(x)]);
    saveas( gcf, 'boat_image&histogram_', 'jpg' );
```

after correct switch :)

```
%boat_image&histogram
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(I02);
subplot(1,2,2)
[cts,x] = imhist(I02);
stem(x,cts);
ylim([0,max(cts)]);
saveas( gcf, 'boat_image&histogram__', 'jpg' );
```

[image]

It was added;[image]

There is a big visual gap both first histogram and the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use

```
ylim([0,max_val])
```

where `max_val` is the greatest y-value you want to have displayed.

You could even do that directly using

```
h = hist(your_data);
ylim([0,max(h)]);
```

Alternatively when using `imhist` you can use the `stem` command:

```
[cts,x] = imhist(img);
stem(x,cts);
ylim([0,max(cts)]);
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. That can be because of the imhist command. :/

Comment: It does work for me, what is the problem youu're encountering?

Comment: I obtained the same result. Y axis values still from 0 to 100

Comment: What about the next solution I added?

Comment: I shared the results above.

Comment: You switched up `x` and `cts`.

Comment: still doesn't work :/ Btw, I want to keep x axis values with grayscale indicator.  I updated the question

Comment: And for horizontal colourbars you can use the usual [`colorbar`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html#bt54x8y) command. Have you ever considered that there might be the possibility to use the docs?

Comment: I tried to use colorbar command but the first histogram was more visual. I will add colorbar version